# Why StringTemplate could be slow?

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I'm using StringTemplate as view layer for my web application. Recently I've measured how much time is spent rendering pages and it's around 50ms for simple pages and 500ms for complex pages. This is too much for my needs, so I'm looking for a way to improve ST's performance. How can I do this?

Most of the time is consumed by the StringTemplate.toString method, so it's not a cache problem.

I actively use anonymous templates and included templates - could this be the cause?

Comment: Not a cache problem?  What if you cached the resultant String?

Comment: This is what I'm planning to do to fix the problem temporarily, but I'd prefer a fast view engine to caching.

Comment: @Fixpoint: Could you please post sourcecode you are using to benchmark ST?

Comment: The code isn't accessible to me any more, unfortunately (I left the company). Another important issues became a priority then and I couldn't get back to investigating this problem.

Comment: I'll accept Terrence's answer, since it could be of use for other people discovering this question. And also because he's the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use write() not toString then writing to your stream.  write() will render and transmit w/o buffering. big difference.
Ter

Comment: Could you clarify? Currently I'm doing this: `response.getWriter().print(template);`

Comment: I've tried `template.write(new AutoIndentWriter(response.getWriter()));` - almost no improvement.

Comment: really?  For Java version that makes huge differ for large templates.

Answer (score 1):

Is that *the* Terence Parr?

I think what Terence meant is

```
template.write(new AutoIndentWriter(response.getWriter()));
```

however I can not beieve that will make any noticeable difference.

You should time two things separately

```
String str = template.toString();  // 1
response.getWriter().print(str);   // 2
```

the slowness is probably on the 2nd line which involves IO.

Comment: I've just measured (1) and (2). Unfortunately, the problem is in `toString`; `print` takes very little time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `toString()` Memory is going to large.

Check your memory when run load test with `toString()` case.

If your memory is enough. Two case is the same time.